# Excel: Find identical values & return different values from same rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Ok, I hit a stop here and don't even know where to begin.

The scenario (interface between two student information systems) is as follows:

I have two worksheets W1 (roster comprising all available course IDs and their corresponding grades) and W2 (roster comprising apl student IDs and their corresponding grade). If two values are identical in columns A of W1 and W2 (i. e. if the grade of a given course matches the grade of a student), a different value from the same row in columns B of W1 and W2 (i. e. the course IDs and the stusent IDs) shall be returned in columns A and B of W3.

The catch: A given value x will occur as multiple instances in both W1 (multiple courses share an identical grade, obviously) and W2 (the same goes for students), and for each of those instances in W1, all matching values from W2 should be returned in W3 (such that there will be list matching each student ID with multiple course IDs).

Does this make sense? Am I overexplaining?

As this just exceeds my Excel skills by far, I'll be immensely grateful for any directions provided!

Cheers! 
Neven

EDIT: I added a visual sketch of the Scenario. Looks like modern art. Also, there are Courses that comprise students of different classes (e. g. "05a~05b"), so instead of identity (e. g. 05a = 05a), a subset function (e. g. 05a~05b CONTAINS 05a) should be sufficient.

[SCREENSHOT OF PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jpxO.png)

Comment: A couple screen shots with examples of what you are starting with and what you are looking for would help.

Comment: Could you provide a sample or screenshot about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for would likely require VBA. I might be over simplifying things with this cheap solution, but...   If necessary use a VLOOKUP to get the details in the one schedule the information on. Then turn on auto filter (Data>Filter) Apply the Number Filter Greater Than.  This will give you the list you are looking for. Copy and paste the results into a new worksheet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but you're right in that afaik VLOOKUP will provide the data for any given lookup value, but it won't be an automatic process. I suppose I'll repost/retag as VBA-related?